# EditText form: "done" key passes focus back to the first visible EditText on screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-view

I have a scrollview that is populated with fairly generic EditTexts dynamically. Flow appears to work correctly: The user fills out a field, hits the "next" button on the soft keyboard, and focus passes to the next EditText in line.

On the final EditText, the "next" button is replaced by "done", as Android realizes there are no more views to focus on in the downwards direction. On pages where there aren't many fields (and thus, no scrolling), this works correctly. The "done" key closes the keyboard and the user can proceed to the next page. However, on a page where there are more EditTexts and scrolling occurs, then when the user hits the "done" key on the final EditText, focus is sent to the first visible EditText, rather than closing the keyboard and removing focus as expected. I am not sure why this is happening and this is causing a major headache.

Additionally, I have another almost identical problem that may be solved by the exact same solution. When a user has scrolled down and then hits a button on the action bar, the first visible EditText gains focus. I do not want this to happen. I'd prefer if the current EditText loses focus on the button press, but it appears that the `onFocusChangeListener` is not being triggered when I click on the button.

Any help would really be appreciated! Here is some code:

My generic EditText layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextRow"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/cursor_white" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The layout that holds the list of TextViews(EditTexts):

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:gravity="center"
            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="7"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:id="@+id/form_view"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

My `onFocusChangeListener`:

```
if (hasFocus){
                if (item.itemFormat.equals("currency")){
                    s = s.replaceAll("\\$", "").replaceAll(",", "");
                }
                text.setText(s);
                ((EditText)text).selectAll();
                imm.showSoftInput(text, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
        }
        else {
            //storing values for form happens here
            text.clearFocus();
        }
```

Comment: why do you have two linearLayouts in The layout that holds the list of EditTexts?

Comment: Scrollview can only hold one child view. The view itself has one title textview and then a list of dynamically generated EditTexts, which go into the Linear Layout `form_view`, but I also wanted to maintain the height of the title whether there are enough edittexts to fill the screen or not.